# Word meaning 'To be pulled'

Tags: synonyms, antonyms, latin

I am looking for a word that means 'to be pulled' in that same sense of propelled or compelled means to be forced or urged forward.

Ideally, it would use the same base *pel*. Searching Google and Wiktionary isn't helping much.

**Clarification**

I am not looking for an antonym, per se.

When you say "I am compelled to ..." you are implying something unstated is acting upon you. For all intents and purposes "I am compelled to (do thing)" is equivalent to "I am compelled (by unstated thing/person) to (do thing)"

Using compelled can imply an actor, that isn't you, moving you in a direction away from itself.

I am looking for a word that, in a similar sense, has an actor acting upon you, but moving you toward itself.

*Drawn* would be a a good example of the kind of word I am looking for, *but* it doesn't (in my mind) imply an actor in the same way. I guess, because one is compelled to action, but one is drawn to a person or place.

**A Note**

Upon further thinking, the closest word I can think of is *called*, as in "I am called to (do thing)". There can be an implication of a hidden actor, **but** one cannot be *called* to change his/her state. One can be **compelled** to change his or her state. This is to say, one can be both **compelled to do** and **compelled to be**, but only **called to do**.

**I do accept that there may not indeed be a word well-suited for the idea I am trying to express.**

Comment: "Drawn", perhaps?

Comment: Compelled is your word. *pro* is forward, *com* is with/together. Impulse has the same root, as does compulsion.

Comment: The Latin verb for 'pull' is _traho,, trahere, trāxī, tractum_. _Pellō, pellere, pepulī, pulsum_ means 'to drive out, repel, fend off'. Doesn't feature pulling, only pushing. But a participle meaning 'to be pulled' would be the Latin gerund _trahendum_.

Comment: @JohnLawler *Traction* is popular, (ODO, "The action of drawing or pulling a thing over a surface, especially a road or track")

Comment: NoBrand, I am not sure I get the question right. How about a usage example?

Comment: Kind of *beckon,* maybe? "I will go home to spend a week or so and then join him again, where I hope to revisit N.C, S.C., Virginia, and some of the other great states that beckon." (Billie Sue Mosiman, *From a High Window* , Smashwords, 2011). **beckon:** " 1.2 Appear attractive or inviting" (ODO http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/beckon )

Comment: lured certainly comes to mind where an actor is directly exerting an influence to pull you towards them.

Comment: this is one of those questions where if the OP would very simply **give an example**, everything would be OK

Comment: Perhaps 
 
"Instigated" ? (instigate means incite/suggest/encourage/urge someone to do something).

Answer (score 1):

When I think of an actor exerting some influence to draw you towards them, the terms that come to mind to me are words like: Lure, entice, beguile, charm, captivate, etc. which generally differ mostly in how people may automatically assume whether the intent is good or nefarious.

Answer (score 0):

As John Lawler pointed out, for an opposite, you need something built on the Latin root for pull.

You can use "attracted", but unfotunately that word has come to mean a more subtle, emotional "pull" rather than a physical pull.

You could use "distracted", but that also has a weaker meaning, mentally being pulled away from what one is conentrating on. And normally this is only applied to people (your question did not state whether you needsd a word that applies to persons, things, or both.)

And "tract" exists in English, but it usually means to distribute pamphlets promoting a cause, such as a religious tract.

And "tractor" has come to mean a farm vehicle (or the engined part of a tractor-trailer rig (aka a "semi).

Star Trek has "tractor beams", which pull objects toward the ship. But as of yet, these have not been invented. The closest we have now are strong electromagnets.

So English could have adopted the Latin root in its true meaning, but it seems to have adopted it mostly for special uses, and retained "pull" for an object literally causing another object to follow it.

Note: One can refer to "magnetic attraction" as a simile, for a person being drawn toward another person, as well as literally, for a metal object being drawn toward a magnet.

Aha! That's the word we are looking for! DRAW/DRAWN. As a horse draws a wagon.

And yet another two: "tow" and "tug".  These both imply some sort of physical connection; e.g. a "tow rope", but could also be used figuratively:  "She tugged at my heartstrings".

Comment: Why not *traction* itself?

Comment: That does not preclude or render deprecated the basic sense of the word. "The action of drawing or pulling something over a surface, especially a road or track" (ODO) http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/traction

Comment: Per ODO already cited. It incidentally **is** the primary meaning. :) Are we missing something here?

Comment: I asked the Prof. because we can't think of a proper verb form (See my comment under OP). Let's see what the others have to say, too.

Comment: @Kris You seem to be missing how dictionaries like ODO work. They list the earliest and most etymologically transparent uses first, and then derived and abstracted uses later. The order in which definitions appear is completely orthogonal to the currency of each definition.

Comment: drawn was the first suggestion from HotLicks.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you could consider **'impel**'; most definitions and usage suggest that's it's a synonym for *'compel'*: to urge forward.

But [a post on grammarbook.com](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/compel-vs-impel/) makes a distinction whereby 'impel' acts through an *incentive* rather than an (external) forced constraint.

> *Compel* means to constrain someone in some way to yield or do what one wishes.
>
> Examples:
>   to compel a debtor to pay; Fate compels us to face danger and trouble.
>
> *Impel* means to provide a strong force, motive, or incentive toward a certain end.
>
> Examples:
>   The wind impelled the ship; Curiosity impels her to ask questions.
>
> **It might help, in some instances, to think of impel as the carrot and compel as the stick.**

(My emphasis).

Only you can judge whether that is enough to carry the 'pulling' imagery you're after.

(EDIT: sorry, I didn't realise how old this question was. But I'll leave this answer here.)